# Short form of «versus» as «vs»

Tags: uso-de-palavras, abreviações

In English I can write *A versus B*, *A vs B* or *A vs. B*.

Can I do the same in Portuguese?

Also, is the English word *versus* also *versus* in Portuguese?

I need to used it in sentence like Chicago time versus GMT time. So can I say Chicago time vs. GMT time?

Comment: @JorgeB. But the sample sentence should be in Portuguese, I think.

Comment: @Jacinto eu só copiei o comentário do Tony e o passei para a pergunta.

Comment: I know. I had seen Tony's comment. My comment is addressed at Tony too: your question is about the use of *versus* and its abreviations in Portuguese, so it would be better to include the Portuguese sentence in which you want to use the word.

Comment: My example: _tempo Chicago vs. horário de Nova Iorque_. I use it in a table caption. One column ls about Chicago time and another column is about New York  time. So this is not sports. So I may not be able to use _x_ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do the same in Portuguese.

About the use of *x*: It is very common in Brazilian Portuguese. I am not sure about the use of *x* (for *vs*) in Portugal, but [Artefacto’s answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3214/1082) gives some hints about it.

In Brazilian Portuguese *x* is often used in texts about sports matches as well. I don’t like it, but people do write *o jogo Corinthians x Palmeiras* in Brazilian papers and websites. The hyphen or dash (*o jogo Corinthians-Palmeiras*) is rarely used for this purpose in Brazil.

I see no problem using *horário de Chicago vs. horário GMT* (or *vs* or *versus*) in a table caption. I would use it myself.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the general case, but in the case of sports games, I've seen what would be written as "vs." in the US written as "x" in Portuguese:

> A x B

If you [search the Portuguese Stack Overflow site for "x"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=x), you will find (hidden amongst all the other uses for "x" in programming) many examples of "x" being used where "vs." would be used in English, both in question titles and question bodies:

- > [Phonegap **x** aplicação nativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53465/8244)
- > [REST **x** Web Services: são a mesmas coisas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120308/8244)
- > [Existe alguma diferença de consumo de memória em gravar os elementos HTML **x** objetos jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96424/8244)

But you will also find "vs." used for this, just like in English.

---

[*versus*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/versus) is a word in Portuguese, with the same meaning and spelling as in English, but a slightly different pronunciation: /vérsus/ (as this is Portuguese, the final /us/ means English "oosh", not "uhss".) The Priberam dictionary gives [*contra*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/contra) as an exact synonym, meaning *against*. In some phrases, *contra* might be a more natural choice (just as *against* might in English).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *versus* (abbr. *vs.*) is used in Portuguese, with the [same meaning](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/versus) as in [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/versus#Preposition), *against*, *in opposition to*, *in contrast with* (i.e., not in its etymological sense). Here are some examples taken from [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CETEMPUBLICO):

> PT: Depois do episódio BCP **«versus»** BPA, agora é a vez de a Caixa Geral de Depósitos vir a público dizer que vai lançar uma Opa sobre o banco espanhol Simeon.
>   EN: After the episode BCP [bank] ***versus*** BPA [bank], now it's Caixa Geral de Depósitos' [bank] turn to publicly announce a takeover bid over the Spanish bank Simeon. [in 1994, BCP launched a takeover bid over BPA]
>
> PT: Rumores postos a circular em Nova Iorque sobre um possível afastamento do Ministro das Finanças do Japão Hashimoto face aos últimos escandâlos financeiros verificados em Tokyo tiveram alguma influência no comportamento do ien **versus** dólar e marco.
>   EN: Rumors in New York about a possible removal of the Japanese Finance Minister Hashimoto given the latest financial scandals in Tokyo had some influence on the behavior of the Ien ***versus*** the Dollar and Mark.

I disagree with Dan Getz when he says that *x* will generally be used instead of *vs.* in the case of sports games. That may be true if you're showing a table with a list of games, but people don't write (let alone say) *o jogo Sporting x Benfica* (*the game Sporting vs. Benfica*). *Versus* is not used either; they write *o (jogo) Sporting-Benfica*.

Comment: No Corpus do Português há uns 30 exemplos de *vs*, uma metade com ponto, outra sem. Mas também me parece que qualquer abreviatura deve levar ponto.